# Is their any algorithm for sentence parsing using bigram probability?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, context-free-grammar

I know that the [CKY algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) can parse sentences using production rules probabilities.

Is there any sentence parsing algorithm I can use if I only know words bigram probabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not induce any sort of grammatical structure from bigram probabilities.* You could use bigrams to build a language model, though, which may serve some of the same purposes as a parser.

<sub>* Actually, you might be able to build a very rudimentary chunking algorithm by starting a new chunk whenever bigram probabiity drops below a certain threshold. But this is nowhere near the accuracy / granularity that is going to be useful for most tasks.</sub>